# JavaScript groupBy is not a functio

Tags: javascript, arrays

i want to group my Data with the Name of type

```
const inventory = [
         { name: 'asparagus', type: 'vegetables', quantity: 5 },
         { name: 'bananas',  type: 'fruit', quantity: 0 },
         { name: 'goat', type: 'meat', quantity: 23 },
         { name: 'cherries', type: 'fruit', quantity: 5 },
         { name: 'fish', type: 'meat', quantity: 22 }          
       let result = inventory.groupBy( ({ type }) => type );
```

on above getting error as groupBy is not a functio

Comment: My i know why -ve voting

Comment: Looks like `groupBy` has [very limited browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupBy#browser_compatibility)

Comment: Have you checked compatibility? Doesn't seem to be supported by any major browser

Comment: @MdGosoddin - You've asked about voting. The question doesn't show any indication that you've looked to see why an array wouldn't have `groupBy`, for instance by looking at the specification, MDN, or any other site with decent documentation. Maybe you have, but the question gives no indication of that, and so people see "no research effort" which is one of the reasons for downvoting questions. *(I haven't downvoted the question, but I understand why people did.)*

Comment: @Lissy93  could you please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: @MdGosoddin: To "resolve this issue" you'd either use a browser which supports the specific operation you're trying to perform, or re-write that operation using more widely supported code.  I guess what you'd do here is manually implement what `groupBy` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript arrays don't have a `groupBy` method **yet**. See [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupBy). It's in nightly Firefox builds at the moment and that's all. [The proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-grouping) is Stage 3 so it'll be landing in JavaScript engines before too long, but in the meantime you have to polyfill it. There are various ways to polyfill it, for instance via [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js). (Babel used to do polyfilling, but [now recommends](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage#polyfill) using `core-js` directly.)